# Computation of Hall basis

Tags: lie-algebras, mathematical-software

I am looking for a program that for a given word in a free Lie algebra calculate the coefficients of the word with respect to the Hall basis. Can you suggest me a program?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is the following GAP package (and related ones), which I would recommend:

Willem de Graaf and Serena Cicalo, [LieRing](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/changes/chap3.html) — a GAP package.

The command "FreeLieRing" enables definition and computations in the free Lie algebra, including Hall bases.